Which wildcard characters should I use?
Please help
"string_mod_4"
John Morgen A1
Ali Zayas
Jennifer Benz A2
Desmond Michael Hall A3
Erik Remar
...

At the end of the text, I cannot remove 'A1', 'A2', etc.
they do not work
Replace([string_mod_4];"*A[123456789]";"";1)
Replace([string_mod_4];"*A?";"";1)
Replace([string_mod_4];"*A#";"";1)


Replace does not know wildcards, use something like Access vba Replace/Regex

Consistency of structure is critical in string manipulation.
Assuming there is an A preceding a single digit at end of string (when present at all), consider:
Trim(IIf(x LIKE "*A#", Replace(x, Right(x, 2), ""), x))
Any variation from that assumption will complicate.
If the field is Null, expression will error. In a query, one way to handle that possibility:
IIf(Not x Is Null, Trim(IIf(x LIKE "*A#", Replace(x, Right(x, 2), ""), x)))
RegEx could be more flexible and compact but has a fairly steep learning curve. Also, AFAIK cannot be called directly in query. Would have to build a custom function to perform manipulation and return value. Review Microsoft office Access `LIKE` VS `RegEx`
